# Detect country of iTunes Store in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, itunes-store

In my iPhone app I would like to detect the country of iTunes Store the iPhone user is logged into, e.g. for a user from USA I would like to direct him/her to: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/21/id420075073
and for a user who is logged into the Polish iTunes Store I would like to redirect him to:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/21/id403037872

I know that I could check the locale (e.g. the language),but it might  not always work.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: By it might not always work means ? what problem you faced ?

Comment: I meant that a user can have the language set to English but be logged into Polish iTunes Store, so checking the locale would not give me good result.

Comment: I'm also interrested in this as it could potentially be used to reduce *some* patent-trolls problems.  User is from a country with a known patent-troll parasite infestation (Lodsys anyone)?  Dynamically disable that feature for that country without requiring a build per country.

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

will get you an identifier like e.g. `"US" (United States), "ES" (Spain)`, etc.

Because you find country means no problem. We hope the iTunes store must be Device country.

Comment: As I said in my question I knew I could check the locale, however, one could have language set to English but be logged into Polish iTunes Store.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all.