# Get App Store Country with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android with mvvmcross but now I have following problem...

In my Core PCL I must done some operation depending on which is the App Store of download.

For translation I have resolved using custom json, TextProviderBuilder and to get language 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString()

Now I'd like to have information on store that must be different to language.

UPDATE
As suggested by Cheesbaron, that is a platform issue that must be resolved in each View. Than how it's possible to access to that information on Xamarin Android and iOS?

Comment: This isn't mvvmcross specific, you need to find out how you do that on either platform you are targeting.

Comment: Updated with reference platform

Comment: What exact information do you need and why?

Comment: Apple/Play Store Country name or in general I'd like to understand from which country store was downloaded app

Comment: I don't think that information is available anywhere. Reading similar questions just on platform specific tags here on SO indicates that it is not possible. The ipa/apk files do not contain such information. Also I am not sure why you need that information in the first place...

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this in a PCL.  You'll have to pass in a reference from your main assembly, or use a device specific assembly to get it.  Here is another question about doing this on iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212055/detect-country-of-itunes-store-in-ios